# Echo "selected" inquiries and questions

Tags: php, html, mysql

I was following a tutorial on PHP and HTML on how to use option=selected, but I am confused.

Here is my code:

```
<form name ="rating" method ="POST" action ="" /> 
<? echo "<input type = \"hidden\" name = accountID value = " . $row['accountID'] . ">";?>
<select name="rating">
    <? $values = array('','Very Bad','Bad','Average','Above Average');

    for ($i =0; $i < count($values); $i = $i + 1){
        echo "<option value = \"$i\"" . if ($rating == $i + 1) {echo "selected";} . "> $values[$i] </option>"; 
    }    
    ?>  
</select>
<input type ="Submit" name ="formSubmit" value ="Submit">
</form>    
<?
```

What I am trying to achieve is to have whatever option is stored in the database to be selected by default. What am I missing in the code?

Comment: You're missing the part where you get the selected option from the database...

Comment: Sorry, I do not know what you mean.. I am pretty new to this. Can you tell me how I can get the selected option from the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this out it will be what u want

```
  <form name ="rating" method ="POST" action ="" > <?php

echo "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'accountID' value = '" . $row['accountID'] . "' >";

?>
    <select name="rating">

        <? $values = array('','Very Bad','Bad','Average','Above Average');

        for ($i =0; $i < count($values); $i = $i + 1){ ?>
            <option value = "$i"  <?php if ($rating == $i + 1) {echo " selected='selected'" ;} ?> > $values[$i] </option>
          <?php 
        }

        ?>

        </select>
        <input type ="Submit" name ="formSubmit" value ="Submit" />
        </form>

    <?
```

EDIT:

yes this variable `$rating` is not defined . so try to define it like that

```
  if (isset $POST['rating']) {$rating = $POST['rating'];}else {$rating = 0 ;}
```

put it before this `form` somewhere inside php tag

Comment: Hi Peter. Just one more thing. 

In the drop-down menu, it says "Notice: Undefined variable: rating in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/index.php on line 64 > $values['$i']" - am I missing an escape?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing at least a space in this line of code and you can't put an `if` statement in your string the way you tried. Try something like this:

```
echo "<option value = \"$i\"" . (($rating == $i + 1) ? " selected" : "") . "> $values[$i] </option>";
```

Comment: Thanks. I made these changes :). My last request is, I want to know what I am missing that is breaking the page. njk told me I am missing the part where I get the selected option from the database. What should I do to get the selected option from the database?

Comment: I don't know your database schema and it depends on that. At the moment none of us knows where the `$rating` variable comes from.

Comment: Ah. $rating is under 

if (isset($_POST['formSubmit'])){
$rating = $_POST['rating'[;
$accountID = $_POST['accountID'];

Comment: I have 6 columns, and they are:
accountID, accountName, website, rating, imageURL, and comments.

Rating is a form.

Comment: Would you like me to post the entire code? 

https://www.dropbox.com/s/x1mzqg8x0m7ay5m/index.php

Here is my dropbox link.

Comment: Then the comparison is wrong and it should be `$rating == $i`

Comment: phew... Line 32 is incorrect. 92-101 should be moved near the top to ensure $rating is set.

Comment: Benjamin, thank you SO much for the corrections on line 32 and 92-101. It worked!

Answer (score 0):

make sure the following comparison is correct:

```
if ($rating == $i + 1)
```

we cannot tell what the $rating variable is from the code you have given. I expect, since you give the options the value:

```
value='$i'
```

that the comparison should be:

```
if ($rating == $i)
```